# CentOS bond or eth interface should have firewall rule?

Tags: networking, iptables, bonding

There is a bond0 bond device. It consists about eth0 and eth1.

Only bond0 interface has an IP address.

**Q:** Which interface should have the iptables firewall rules (layer3)?

Only bond0 or all 3 or only the two eth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules related to layer3 created on `bond0` will match both interfaces.

You can test with `tcpdump` and these simple rules

```
iptables -A INPUT -i bond0 -j ACCEPT # Accept everything coming in bond0
iptables -P INPUT DROP # Default drop
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your bond type which has to have ip address. Other thing is your `bond0` device should have the firewall rules, not the two `ethx` devices which build up `bond0`.